# Do I have to override .__init__ in my subclass, or can I just add a few variables?

Tags: python, class, oop, init

In my `Class Items():` I have an `.__init__` function that initiates 7 variables. Then I have a subclass `Toys(Items):` it uses all 7 variables initiated as the Items + 3 extra variables. All of the variables are set when the object is created.

Simplified Example of what I’m doing now:

```py
Class Items():

    def __init__(self, name, color, size):
        self.name = name
        # etc. 

Class Toys(Items):
    def __init__(self, name, color, size, shape, noise)
        self.name = name
        # etc.
```

I’ve tried, static variables but it doesn’t work since the variables affect all instances of Toys and each one needs to be different.
I’ve tried using the Super function but it kicks errors for having too many args.
I’m currently working through @classmethod to see what happens.

Am I already doing it properly by overriding, or is there a better way to work the problem?

Comment: "I’ve tried using the Super function but it kicks errors for having too many args" - can you show us your attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `args, kewargs`

```py
class Items():
    def __init__(self, name, color, size):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        self.size = size

class Toys(Items):
    def __init__(self, shape, noise, *args, **kwargs):
        self.shape = shape
        self.noise = noise
        super().__init__(*args, *kwargs)
        
t = Toys('L', '12db', 'abc', 'red', '20cm')
t.color # red
```

Comment: Can I ask...I would have intuitively put `args`/`kwargs` into the base class, and in the subclass call `super().__init__()` with the fixed parameters. The reason being that the base class probably has fixed parameters, while inherited types may differ in the needed arguments. Is there something wrong with my thinking?

Comment: maybe true, sometimes we don't mess up with the base class since many other classes may depend on it!

Comment: This was it! I completely forgot about args/kwargs like a dingo. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

do you want to do something like this? This works but doesn't scale that well, and you might consider using kwargs etc. if you need it to be more flexible.

```py
Class Items():

    def __init__(self, name, color, size):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        self.size = size
        # etc. 

Class Toys(Items):
    def __init__(self, name, color, size, shape, noise)
        super().__init__(name, color, size)
        self.shape = shape
        self.noise = noise
        # etc.
```